# how to consolidate the process using powershell

Tags: powershell

guys do you know which command that consolidate a process my command here listed all the process

```
$processtest = Get-process -name teams | Sort-Object -Property ws -Descending | Select-Object processname, @{Name="Mem Usage(MB)";Expression={[math]::round($_.ws / 1mb*2)}}, @{Name="Mem Usage(%)";Expression={[math]::round($_.ws / 1mb*2)/100}}
```

here's the output

```
ProcessName Mem Usage(MB) Mem Usage(%)
----------- ------------- ------------
Teams                 954         9.54
Teams                 930          9.3
Teams                 310          3.1
Teams                 299         2.99
Teams                 274         2.74
Teams                 168         1.68
Teams                 152         1.52
Teams                  37         0.37
Teams                  37         0.37
Teams                  25         0.25
```

i was planning to put if command if $processtest reach 90% on a specific application it will restart i have the code for that i just need to consolidate this services

Comment: If all you want it the total of a given value, say `Mem Usage(%)`, then add something like `| Measure-Object -Sum 'Mem Usage(%)'` to the end of your command.

Comment: not the expected output i want it to be on a table i was planning to put multiple get-process because i have 3 applications that needs to monitor their memory consumption

Comment: i have 1 code but it does not allow me to select specific service below is the sample code

$processMemoryUsage = Get-WmiObject WIN32_PROCESS | Sort-Object -Property ws -Descending | Select-Object -first 5 processname, @{Name="Mem Usage(MB)";Expression={[math]::round($_.ws / 1mb*1.8)}}, @{Name="Mem Usage(%)";Expression={[math]::round($_.ws / 1mb*1.8)/100}}

Answer (score 0):

You can consolidate the the process data like this:

```
Get-Process |
    Group-Object Name |
    ForEach-Object {$totalMem = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).TotalPhysicalMemory}{
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Name       = $_.Name
            Count      = $_.Count
            WorkingSet = ($_.Group.WS | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
            MemPercent = [Math]::Round((($_.Group.WorkingSet64 | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum) / $totalMem, 3) * 100
        }
    } | Sort-Object WorkingSet -Descending | Select-Object -First 5
```

Which gives the top 5 processes by `WorkingSet`, similar to this:

```
Name                     Count WorkingSet MemPercent
----                     ----- ---------- ----------
chrome                      17 2239315968       13.1
svchost                     86  805847040        4.7
Memory Compression           1  699019264        4.1
Creative Cloud UI Helper     3  444882944        2.6
SearchApp                    1  287055872        1.7
```

So, for this example, you can see that there are 86 instances of `svchost` with a total `WorkingSet` of 805847040 bytes, which is about 4.7% of the physical memory on the system.

If you want to kill all instances of a given process if their total memory use is over a given percentage, you can do it with slightly reduced code:

```
Get-Process -Name chrome -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' |
    Group-Object Name |
    ForEach-Object {$totalMem = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).TotalPhysicalMemory}{
        if(((($_.Group.WorkingSet64 | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum / $totalMem) * 100) -ge 90) {
            Stop-Process -Name $_.Name -Force
        }
    }
```

Here, all instances of `chrome` will be stopped if together they are using 90% or more of the memory.

Comment: ok it is the same thing as my 2nd code the question here is how can you pick a process to set a condition? to your code since the code is list all the processes,

this is were my 1st code come but the problem is it is listing all the process instead of consilidating them im still trying to find that command thou if you have that command kindly share it to me please thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  You said you wanted a table that shows a consolidated value for each process, which is what my code does.  What do you mean by _"how can you pick a process to set a condition"_ ?  If you only want a single process, say, _chrome_, in the output, then simply ask for it at the start: `Get-Process -Name chrome ...` (and you can also drop the sorting and selecting at the end in that case).

Comment: hmmm okok focus only on the 1st code that I've i sent do you know how to consolidate the process? the table result on the 1st code should be the same just consolidate all the it to 1 process instead of multiple

Comment: if you still dont get it you mention this right ? Get-Process -Name chrome 
when you execute that there is alot right ? do you have a way to consolidate all chrome since its the same process ?

im looking for that command but no luck

Comment: _" ... consolidate all chrome since its the same process"_  So, by "consolidate" do you mean that you want a single object (i.e single line in the output table) that shows the accumulated memory usage for all processes called, say, `chrome`?  If this is the case, then that is exactly what my example does.  Each line in the output is the total memory use for all processes with a given name - the 'Count' property (column) give the number of instances consolidated in that item (e.g. 17 instances of `chrome` in the example above).

Comment: but how do you put command there?
for example i want to put if statement ,
how can i put a condition were if chrome memory is 90% then do this?,

Comment: I've added an extra example to my answer.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer :-)

Comment: thanks again boxdog super appreciated

Comment: Hi boxdog need 1 more assistance how do you convert this to CPU?